# How to use Ionic after installation in an existing angular project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have already installed ionic with the command `npm install -g @ionic/cli native-run cordova-res` and then I did this command ng add @ionic/angular and it did help that it added the line `"@ionic/angular": "^6.3.2 ",`
in `package.json` but when I add import of ionic
`import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular'`
I get dozens of bugs . '.node_modules/@ionic/angular/directives/proxies.d.ts(725,21): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Project/MCProject/MCProject-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'...
and more
what can i do this import without this bug??? Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do tow simple steps:
1.`npm install --save @ionic/angular`
2.`npm start`
I tried for two whole days but it didn't work.
and when I did it everything worked.
G‍ood Luck:)

Comment: What does npm start have to do with the question?

Comment: to run the project